# Is it possible to run ADB on multiple devices using Hyper-V?

Tags: automation, android, hyper-v

What I would like to do is use Hyper-V to set up N number of VM's, each one being used to run a different set of tests on a different Android device. It seems like Hyper-V doesn't accept the input of the USB device.

My question is: Is it possible to run ADB on multiple devices using Hyper-V? If so, how?

Comment: Am I assuming correctly that *running* ADB isn't actually the problem, but routing the devices from the host to the guest is?

Comment: That and getting each specific VM to recognize a specific device. I'm able to set up ADB and such...